# How to get initial parameter after "?" using URLSearchParams

Tags: javascript, url

If my browser is on http://example/cars?type=ford, `searchParams.get(type)` returns `null`, and if it on  http://example/cars?type=ford&type=dodge, it returns `dodge`.  How can the first parameter after the question mark be included.  I am operating Chrome Version 64.0.3282.167 (Official Build) (64-bit).

```
my.filter=function(type,value){
    var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.href);
    var search=searchParams.get(type);
    console.log(search)
    if(search) {
        search=search.split(',');
        if(!search.indexOf(value)) {
            search.push(value);
            searchParams.set(type,search.join(','));
        }
    }
    else searchParams.append(type,value);
    var url=searchParams.toString();
    console.log(url);
    //window.location.href = url;
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing in `window.location.href`, and not `window.location.search` …?

Comment: @CBroe  No good reason, just ignorance.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> !search.indexOf(value)
> ```

`indexOf` returns `-1` (a true value) if there is no match, but `0` (a false value) if there is a match at position 0.

You can't test for falseness to see if there isn't a match!

Test against `-1` instead.

```
search.indexOf(value) === -1
```